# Error while trying to delete a sqlite table in haskell

Tags: sqlite, haskell, sql-delete

I have a problem when trying to delete a complete table in sqlite, could someone help me?

code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Database.SQLite.Simple
import Database.SQLite.Simple.FromRow

data TestField = TestField Int String deriving (Show)

instance FromRow TestField where
fromRow = TestField <$> field <*> field

main :: IO()
main = do
conn <- open "db1.sqlite"
execute conn "DROP TABLE tabela"
close conn
```

Returning the error:

```
delete.hs:14:3: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘IO a0’
              with actual type ‘q0 -> IO ()’
• Probable cause: ‘execute’ is applied to too few arguments
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: execute conn "DROP TABLE tabela"
  In the expression:
    do { conn <- open "db1.sqlite";
         execute conn "DROP TABLE tabela";
         close conn }
  In an equation for ‘main’:
      main
        = do { conn <- open "db1.sqlite";
               execute conn "DROP TABLE tabela";
               close conn }
      Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`execute` requires a query parameter.  From the haddocks:

```
execute :: ToRow q => Connection -> Query -> q -> IO ()
```

Try

```
execute conn "DROP TABLE tabela" ()
```